# What connectors needed to mate Pi4B to KVM switch with video on DB-9 and P/S2 keyboard and mouse?

Tags: display, keyboard, mouse, connectors

```
First off I don't even have a Pi yet, ordered it yesterday.
```

I've 2 PIIIs on the desktop and a Sony SDM-HS73 display all tied together througn a KVM switch that takes P/S2 connectors for keyboard and mouse plus the old DB-15 VGA connector for the monitor.
I've looked at the RPI site and wasn't able to find anything really definitive. I think all I need for the mouse and keyboard are USB.A male > P/S2 female adapters which hopefully I can get at Walmart. The video connectors I'm less clear on. Hopefully some one here has already solved this puzzle and can point me in the right direction.
Any pointers towards more specific docs too would be appreciated.
Thanks,
MikeMc

Comment: Donate your KVM to a museum.